# View pager for my gallery my list item

Tags: android

I am very new to android,I am trying to display my grid item in view pager when i click each item it display in view pager but i gt error so please any one help me
in my view pager adapter three error 
GalleryAdapter(Activity,ArrayList)in Gallery cannot applied to GalleryViewpager

Non static method getcount() can't be referenced from a static context

non-static 'listFlag'  can't be referenced from a static context

Any one please help me,

this is my main activity adapter class
here my 
**GalleryAdapter.class**

```
    public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    public ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
    private Activity activity;

    public GalleryAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Integer> listFlag)     {
        super();

        this.listFlag = listFlag;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return listFlag.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Integer.toString(listFlag.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public ImageView imgViewFlag;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder view;
        LayoutInflater inflator = activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView==null)
        {
            view = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.gallery_viewlayout, null);

            view.imgViewFlag = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);

            convertView.setTag(view);
        }
        else
        {
            view = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //view.txtViewTitle.setText(listCountry.get(position));
        view.imgViewFlag.setImageResource(listFlag.get(position));

        return convertView;
    }


}
```

here my viewpager activity class

**GalleryViewpagger.class**

```
    public class GalleryViewpagger extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    int position;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_viewpagger);

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        Intent p = getIntent();
        position = p.getExtras().getInt("id");
     GalleryAdapter galleryadapter=new GalleryAdapter(this);
        List<ImageView> images = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

        for (int i = 0; i < GalleryAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
            imageView.setImageResource(GalleryAdapter.listFlag[i]);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
            images.add(imageView);
        }

        // Set the images into ViewPager
        ImagePagerAdapter pageradapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(images);
        VerticalViewPager viewpager = (VerticalViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
        // Show images following the position
        viewpager.setCurrentItem(position);

    }
}

my 
MainActivity.class

    public class AlbumView extends Fragment {

    private GalleryAdapter mAdapter;

    private ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;

    private GridView gridView;
    public AlbumView() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_album_view, container, false);

        prepareList();

        // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
        mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity(), listFlag);

        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (GridView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                // Launch ImageViewPager.java on selecting GridView Item
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryViewpagger.class);

                // Show a simple toast message for the item position

                // Send the click position to ImageViewPager.java using intent
                i.putExtra("id", position);

                // Start ImageViewPager
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



    return rootview;

    }
    public void prepareList() {
        listFlag = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        listFlag.add(R.drawable.imagabun);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.imagabun);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.imagabun);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.imagabun);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.imagabun);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.imagabun);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.imagabun);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.imagabun);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);
        listFlag.add(R.drawable.bunnyarj);



    }



}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line on your GalleryViewpagger, you need 2 objects to construct the Adapter.

```
GalleryAdapter galleryadapter=new GalleryAdapter(this);
```

instead, it must be like:

```
GalleryAdapter galleryadapter=new GalleryAdapter(this, listFlag);
```

or something like that. Find an object (listFlag) and pass it to the constructor.

Update your code and let's see if other problems will happen again or not.

**UPDATE**

Since you initialize the listFlag in your MainActivity, just create another constructor for your GalleryAdapter which takes only 1 argument, Activity.

And try to make the listFlag object 'static' in that GalleryAdapter class so GC won't delete it.

Comment: GalleryAdapter galleryadapter=new GalleryAdapter(this, listFlag); is not working,when i try this line i am gettion this error  cannot resolve symbol listflag@Tuaygc

Comment: Create another constructor for your GalleryAdapter and pass only the activity object(in your case, use 'this' keyword). If you do that, you must make listFlag static in the GalleryViewpagger, like: `code`                                                      public GalleryAdapter(Activity activity)     {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
} @vishnu

Comment: yes i am created that but my constructor is invisble android.app.activity is never used

Comment: Have you changed your code? So you must call like GalleryAdapter galleryadapter=new GalleryAdapter(this); again, not with listFlag. Can you update your GalleryAdapter and GalleryViewpagger code? @vishnu

Comment: yes and after that  i am getting this line error  GalleryAdapter.getCount(); i++) in my Gelleryviewpagerview   Non static method getcount() can't be referenced from a static context @Tuaygc

Comment: try changing your for loop from: `code` for (int i = 0; i < GalleryAdapter.getCount(); i++) { this to -->  `code` for (int i = 0; i < galleryadapter.getCount(); i++) { basically, don't make a static call.

Comment: in my for loop last error this one ,array type expected found java.util.arraylist<java.lang.integer>    in line of  imageView.setImageResource(GalleryAdapter.listFlag[i]);@Tuaygc

Comment: You shouldn't get that error if you've made listFlag "static" in GalleryAdapter. `code` public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
public static ArrayList<Integer> listFlag;
private Activity activity;

Comment: Thanq so much ,i resolved my issue by following your step ,thanq so much @Tuaygc